# i keep running in 'int' object is not subscriptable ( board[random_coord[0],random_coord[1]] = 'O' )

Tags: python

```
import random

#creating board
board = []

for canvas in range(0,3):
    board.append(["H"] * 3)

#print board function
def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print (" ".join(row))

coord = [ [0, 0],[0,1],[0,2],
          [1, 0],[1,1],[1,2],
          [2, 0],[2,1],[2,2] ]
   
col = int(input("Chose a column: ")) - 1
row = int(input("Chose a row: ")) - 1
    
#bot chose col and row
if [col,row] in coord:
    coord.remove([col,row])
random_coord = random.randint(0, len(coord) - 1)
    
board[random_coord[0],random_coord[1]] = 'O'

print(random_coord)
print(coord)
```

the line         board[random_coord[0],random_coord[1]] = 'O'         keep running in 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Okay, so you saw an error message. Did you *read* the error message? Did you *attempt to understand* the error message? What, according to your understanding, is going wrong with the code, and specifically why are you unable to fix it? (Hint: on the previous line, where you have `random_coord = random.randint(0, len(coord) - 1)`, what do you think that means? What do you expect `random_coord` to end up looking like? Does it make sense to you, to use that result in the way that you're doing?)

Comment: I *guess* that what you are trying to do is pick a random value out of the `coord` list, and use that sub-list to index into `board`. This leaves two questions that you should be able to answer for yourself: 1) when you look at the documentation for the `random` module, do you see anything designed to let you choose a value out of a list? 2) what does indexing into a list of lists normally look like?

Comment: thanks. my code now is             random_coord = random.randint(0, len(coord) - 1)
                                                   coord_chose = coord[random_coord]
    
                                                  board[coord_chose[0], coord_chose[1]] = 'O'                                        but i keep running in      list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: That's because you didn't answer my questions from the second comment.

Comment: ok give me 1 minutes

Comment: i don't really know, can u help me with more specific hint !

Comment: karl, i think random.choice let me chose a value of a list

Comment: Accessing element in a nested list by `ls[x][y]` not `ls[x,y]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
board[random.randint(0, len(coord[0]))][random.randint(0, len(coord[0]))] = 'O'
```

or if you want only get one random try this:

```
random_coord = random.randint(0, len(coord[0]))
board[random_coord][random_coord] = 'O'
```

if you want access to 2d list like this `arr[row,col]` you need use `numpy` and convert `list` to `numpy.array` like below:

```
import numpy as np
board = np.array(board)
random_coord = random.randint(0, len(coord[0]))
board[random_coord,random_coord] = 'O'
print(board)

[['H' 'H' 'H']
 ['H' 'H' 'H']
 ['H' 'H' 'O']]
```

Comment: what coord[0] do ?

Comment: @darryl nguyen, you have 2d array and you need random number between `0-2` for this I get len(coord[0]) because in this variable we have len == 2

Comment: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple :(

Answer (score -1):

That's because `random.randint(a, b)` returns a random integer value between `a` and `b`, not an iterable.
In your case, if you want, for example a list of `n` random integer numbers, you can do like this:

```py
random_coord = [random.randint(0, len(coord) - 1) for _ in range(n)]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, this code doesn't solve the problem (and also OP should think more about the code and ask a more specific question). In particular, `len(coord)` is the wrong bounds for generating board coordinates directly; OP wanted to use it to pull pre-made coordinate pairs out of the `coord` list.